# Vue JS async and wait gives error in VSCode

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

```
   methods: {
    async fetchResource (key, url) {
      try {
        this.$data[key] = await this.$fetch(url)
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
      }
    },
  },
```

[I am trying to create an async and await function,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTR31.png) 
 but I keep getting errors in VSCode [I keep getting these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ew6hA.png)

Comment: Please update your answer showing what errors do you get

Comment: If you are useing webpack, Make sure you have the right babel and webpack plugins installed for your project. and also check your eslint configuration if you have one

Comment: Seems jshint doesn't support async-await, which comes in next  (2.10) release  https://github.com/jshint/jshint/pull/3273